# (Ionic Framework) Angular JS filter factory from another factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have three factory in Items, ItemTags , and Tags. How to create custom search that search Items from another factory. Example when i select tag 'Steak' , the Sirloin is shown in list and when i select tag 'Pizza' the Black Pizza is shown in list. Thanks ...

```
 .factory('Items', function() {
      var items = [{
        id: 1,
        name:'Black Pizza',
        main_img:'img/food1.jpg'
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name:'Sirloin',
        main_img:'img/food2.jpg'
      }];

      return {
        all: function() {
          return items;
        },
        remove: function(item) {
          items.splice(items.indexOf(item), 1);
        },
        get: function(itemId) {
          for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (items[i].id === parseInt(itemId)) {
              return items[i];
            }
          }
          return null;
        }
      };
    })

 .factory('ItemTags', function(Items,Tags) {
      // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array


      var itemTags = [{
        id: 1,
        itemId:Items.get(1),
        tagId:Tags.get(0)
      }, {
        id: 2,
        itemId:Items.get(0),
        tagId:Tags.get(1)
      }];

      return {
        all: function() {
          return itemTags;
        },
        remove: function(itemTag) {
          itemTags.splice(itemTags.indexOf(itemTag), 1);
        },
        get: function(itemTagId) {
          for (var i = 0; i < itemTags.length; i++) {
            if (itemTags[i].id === parseInt(itemTagId)) {
              return itemTags[i];
            }
          }
          return null;
        }
      };
    })

.factory('Tags', function() {
      var tags = [{
        id: 0,
        name: 'Steak'
      }, {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Pizza'
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Delicious'
      }];

      return {
        all: function() {
          return tags;
        },
        remove: function(tag) {
          tags.splice(tags.indexOf(tag), 1);
        },
        get: function(tagId) {
          for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
            if (tags[i].id === parseInt(tagId)) {
              return tags[i];
            }
          }
          return null;
        }
      };
    })
```

Thanks for the the_mahasagar for the help:
I am modify function from the mahasagar and add the function into ItemTags

```
 getDataByTag: function(tagId , itemId) {
        for (var i = 0; i < itemTags.length; i++) {
          if (itemTags[i].tagId.id === parseInt(tagId) && itemTags[i].itemId.id===parseInt(itemId)) {
            return itemTags[i];
          }
        }
```

And this is my filter:

```
 $scope.criteriaMatch = function( tagId) {
        return function( item ) {
            var itemTag = ItemTags.getDataByTag(tagId,item.id);
            if(itemTag!=null)
                return true;

            return null;
        };
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per your ques, u did wrong in ItemTags factory.just check and add getDataByTag.

```
.factory('ItemTags', function(Items,Tags) {
// Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array
Items.get(0);
var itemTags = [{
  id: 1,
  itemId:Items.get(2),
  tagId:Tags.get(0)
}, {
  id: 2,
  itemId:Items.get(1),
  tagId:Tags.get(1)
}];

return {
  all: function() {
    return itemTags;
  },
  remove: function(itemTag) {
    itemTags.splice(itemTags.indexOf(itemTag), 1);
  },
  get: function(itemTagId) {
    for (var i = 0; i < itemTags.length; i++) {
      if (itemTags[i].id === parseInt(itemTagId)) {
        return itemTags[i];
      }
    }
    return null;
  },
  getDataByTag: function(itemTagId) {
    for (var i = 0; i < itemTags.length; i++) {
      if (itemTags[i].tagId.id === parseInt(itemTagId)) {
          return itemTags[i];
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
};
})
```

u can get ur data like:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope,Items,Tags,ItemTags) {
$scope.getData = function(Tagid) {
  console.log("ItemTags :"+JSON.stringify(ItemTags.getDataByTag(Tagid)));
}
  $scope.getData(0);
})
```

hope,its the same u want.

Comment: Thank you for correction, This is help , i modify your code